# How can I convert point features into a raster that the original point will be the center of the new cell in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point

I have a problem in ArcGIS, So, I converted rasters to points. After that, I ran extract values to ponts function. Now I want to convert my point features back to raster with the original resolution. The problem is new cells are not at the same location as the old ones because I ran point to raster function. When ArcGIS convert ponts to rasters the points are not in the central of the new cells. Just how you can see on picture.

Comment: You'd have to provide the details of how you're attempting this before we could help. Note that center alignment of more than two points could force an unusably small cell size.

Comment: Firstly, I converted rasters to points. I ran extract values to ponts function. Now I want to convert them back to raster with the original resolution. The problem is new cells are not at the same location as the old ones. Because I ran point to raster function.

Comment: No picture is attached.

Answer (score 1):

I was a little bit confused by your question, but I think I understand it:

When you are converting the points to raster, make sure to set the "Snap Raster" to the original raster you want the new one to align with. You can find "Snap Raster" by clicking "Environments" after you open the convert to raster tool.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/environments/snap-raster.htm